# Error when attempting to access image in my react app

Tags: reactjs, directory

I am unable to access right-arrow.png which is in my images folder. I am trying to access this from src/components/Home. right-arrow.png is located in src/images.

```
import rightArrow from ".../images/right-arrow.png";
```

^this line is giving me the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 3 dots to go up a folder.It should be 2 dots to go up a folder like so:

```
import rightArrow from "../images/right-arrow.png";
```

EDIT: from the image it seems like it needs to go up 2 levels, so:

```
import rightArrow from "../../images/right-arrow.png";
```

Comment: I am getting the same error with this as well

Comment: this works thank you sm! I am curious though, why does the edited answer work and not your first one?

Comment: @Zathura the reason is each `../` represents how many levels you want to go up. so ../ represents go up 1 level, ../../ represents go up 2 levels, and so forth.